# Visual C++ No operator ">>" matches these operands

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, sdl

I have been searching around for a solution to this for a while.  I'm trying to use the ">>" and "<<" operators as shown below but keep getting the error "No operator '>>' matches these operands".  Here are the code snippets:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

...


int blah;
std::string level;

level >> blah;
thisDot.setX(blah);

level >> blah;
thisDot.setY(blah);
```

Several of the posts I have found on this topic have had the solution of simply including `#include <string>`, but as you can see I have included that and am still getting the error.  I have also tried `#include string.h` but that doesn't help either.  Any ideas as to why this would still be happening?...it may be worth noting that I'm using the SDL library.

Comment: That's not possible with `std::string`. Perhaps you are confusing it with stringstream?

Comment: What are you expecting `level >> blah;` to do? Are you expecting it to modify the string?

Comment: Also, don't forget, that C++ does not default primitives declared on the stack, so `blah` will be whatever the value happens to be in the memory that it takes. I'm sure this was meant to be example code, but I can't help but notice the code following `level >> blah` using it.

Comment: I assume he's expecting some kind of `operator >>` that takes an `int &` and sets its value. But to what, I can't imagine. Nor can I figure out how he's expecting the next `>>` to get a different value.

Comment: Maybe he meant `std::cin` since he's taking an int argument?

Comment: I was going through this tutorial: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson24/index.php  it supposed to be getting some values from a file.

Comment: @user1661485, I really suggest you take reading lessons, because there is nothing like `level >> blah` in the tutorial (tip: check the `level` part on the site you've just linked).

Comment: @user1661485 notice that he used `std::ifstream` object not `std::string` to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misread the example. The example is reading from a *file*, not a *string*.

```
 std::string level;
 // ...
 load >> offset;
```

Notice that it is `load` that appears on the left of the `>>`, not `level`.

Comment: Wow...I'm an idiot.  Sorry for the waste of time guys and thanks for help